# Get interacted object in htc Vive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I just start to learn HTC vive app development with unity and want to interact with Object and want to get it as controller interact with it.
Try to learning form [StreamVR Unity Toolkit documentation](https://github.com/thestonefox/SteamVR_Unity_Toolkit/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#prefabs). I found a scene in sample demo where Gameobject are interacting through controller but there are so many scripts involved. I am amazed that on a cube VRTK_InteractalbeObject is attached and it is responding to controller. how can i get interacted object in htc vive.?

Comment: Do you already know how to handle controllers buttons? Based on your answer I will have different answer for you.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski no

Comment: beside long and set of stearmVR toolkit classes can i use own code. it will take too long to learn them first and then try. do u have something

Comment: I will answer this question when I get back to home from work, unless somebody will answer it already. Please wait. I am making games for htc vive so I know how to do all you need.

Comment: And FYI - it is very very easy

Comment: @JerrySwitalski oh man thank u so much i am eagerly waiting for your guide. Dont forget to answer

Comment: Don't worry, I will!

Comment: @JerrySwitalski did u check

Comment: I am still at work - I will make the answer in 2-3 hours.

Comment: You can also use HTC's Vive Input Utility on the asset store - it's even easier with static functions to check buttons and a single script (Basic Grabbable) to attach to Objects to make them grabbable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, here is *one of many solutions* to interact with objects with controllers - I will show here the easiest one.

**A.** Find `[CamerRig]` prefab from **SteamVR folder** and place it in hierarchy:
[image]

**B.** Find `Controller (right)->Model` GameObject in it:

[image]

**C.** Create `GameObject` with `Rigidbody` and `SphereCollider` and place it as child of `Controller (right)->Model` GameObject

**C.1.** Be sure that this object is in same position as `Model GameObject`

**D.** Now play the game, and moving your right vive controller push some other `GameObjects` that have `Rigidbody` and any `Collider`.

**E.** To use vive controller Buttons use this script, and place it on `Controller (right)` GameObject.

```
public class VIVEController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;
    private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller;

    void Start () 
    {
        controller = SteamVR_Controller.Input ((int)trackedObj.index);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (controller.GetPressDown (Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger)) 
        {
            OnTriggerPressed ();
        }

        if (controller.GetPressDown (Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Touchpad)) 
        {
            OnTouchpadPressed ();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerPressed()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnTriggerPresse");
    }

    private void OnTouchpadPressed()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnTouchpadPressed");
    }
}
```

**F.** Assign from inspector `trackedObj` (It is on same `GameObject` as this script)

**G.** Find script `SteamVR_RenderModel` and comment out in method `LoadComponents`

```
        for (int i = 0; i < t.childCount; i++)
        {
            var child = t.GetChild(i);
            child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            StripMesh(child.gameObject);
        }
```

This is necessary, as otherwise your custom `GameObject` with collider that is child of controller model, will become inactive.

Resuming - it is very easy, but you need to do quite few steps. 
Try playing with controllers buttons, to for instance push object only when you press trigger.

As bonus, here is small game I made with same approach:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzX7Iw6cHZ8